# Настройка django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Есть модель объявления и отклика на это объявление:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   text = RichTextUploadingField('Text', blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.headline

class Response(models.Model):
   post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   text = models.TextField()
```

Необходимо оформить страницу на которой будут показываться все отклики на объявления, созданные пользователем и была возможность фильтровать отклики по объявлениям (по полю headline).
Использовал django-filter.

**views.py**

```
class ResponseView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Response
    template_name = 'resposes.html'
    context_object_name = 'responses'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        self.filterset = ResponseFilter(self.request.GET, queryset)
        return self.filterset.qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filterset'] = self.filterset
        context['filter'] = ResponseFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context
```

**filters.py**

```
class ResponseFilter(FilterSet):
    post = ModelChoiceFilter(
        empty_label='все объявления',
        field_name='post',
        queryset=Post.objects.all(),
        label='Поиск по объявлению',
        lookup_expr='exact',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Response
        fields = ['post',]
```

**responses.html**

```
{% block content %}

 <form action="" method="get">
       {{ filterset.form.as_p }}
       <input type="submit" value="Найти" />
   </form>

<div>
    {% if responses %}
        <h2>Отклики:</h2>
    {% for response in responses %}
        <p>Сообщение: {{ response.text }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <h2>Откликов нет!</h2>
    {% endif %}
```

Фильтр работает. Но в фильтре на выбор даются все объявления, даже те, которые не создавал автор. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, что бы в фильтре отображались только те объяления, которые написал пользователь.